# Blurring part of a table cell

Tags: html, css, blur

I have a `<table>` that I would like to overlay a circle on and have everything outside of the circle be blurred. The circle will change position based on a function, so it needs to be dynamic. I know how to do this with an image, but this needs to be a table. I have used the following CSS, but this will only let me blur an entire cell.

`-webkit-filter: blur(10px)`

The two options I can think of would be to overlay some sort of svg that is made up of a square and a circle and blur the space between in the edges (is this possible?), or to apply some sort of blur gradient to the cells that meet the edges of the circle.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Here is an example of what i am trying to accomplish.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5EqT.png

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to do something like this, but it might not be as straightforward as you were hoping.

### JSFiddle Example

My technique involves cloning the entire content area, and overlaying it exactly on top of the original, but only revealing a portion of it.

You can clone the area through javascript (jQuery's `.clone()` works nicely), or you can simply include all the markup again in your HTML, but for a table this large, that's not very efficient.

To reveal only a small circle of it, I placed it all inside of a `div` element that had `overflow: hidden` set, so all the overflow gets cut off.

The tricky part comes with keeping that overlaid position right where it needs to be.

In my example, I have the circle move to follow the mouse. By default, both the circle, and the cloned content are absolutely positioned to the top left of the original content, allowing it to line up, but as my circle moves, the content moves with it, since it lives within the circle (setting `overflow: hidden` causes the circle to act as it would with `position: relative`, containing absolute positions within).

So, to compensate for this, I always move the cloned content an equal amount in the opposite direction as the circle is moving.

Then it's just a matter of blurring the original content, whilst keeping the cloned content crisp.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Works only in Chrome 39, not in FF 34 and will probably not in IE

Comment: The question is centred around a webkit specific blur filter, so I only targeted webkit in my response

Comment: This is great. Thank you for your responses. I am always pleased when i post a question on this site.